# Laplace transform of the square of a first derivative.

Tags: laplace-transform

What is the Laplace transform of the square of a first derivative, i.e $L (dx/dt)^2$?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. You will get better results if you include what you already know or what you have tried already with your question.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably not an enormous amount of simplification possible. You can use the multiplication rule:
$$L[f(t)\,g(t)]=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{c-iT}^{c+iT}F(\sigma)\,G(s-\sigma)\,d\sigma,$$
where the integration is done along the vertical line $\operatorname{Re}(\sigma)=c,$ and which must be in the region of convergence of $F.$ Here
\begin{align*}
F(s)&=L[f(t)]\\
G(s)&=L[g(t)].
\end{align*}
So, noting that
\begin{align*}
L[\dot{f}(t)]&=sF(s)-f(0^-),
\end{align*}
we can write
\begin{align*}
L\left[\left(\dot{f}(t)\right)^{\!2}\right]
&=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{c-iT}^{c+iT}(\sigma F(\sigma)-f(0^-))((s-\sigma)F(s-\sigma)-f(0^-))\,d\sigma.
\end{align*}
And that's probably about as far as you can go.